# Find the method which AJAX GET calls

Tags: php, functions, jquery, ajax, javascript

I need to find bug in a Wordpress site. 
But I can't find the method (function) that the AJAX GET call runs on backend.
That's not admin part of website, but front end part of website.

**important**
I found the url where AJAX call is sent, but don't know how to find the method/function.

code for sending AJAX call looks like this

I have code for sending XMLHttpRequest something like this:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://themes.qnimate.com/qplog/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=logged_in_check");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X_REQUESTED_WITH","xmlhttprequest");
    xhr.onload = function(){
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    xhr.send();
```

There is nothing like add_action() on frontend.

What could you advise?
Any technics, advices?

Comment: firstly use the network monitor to look which AJAX call is send, e.g. with firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Comment: hello, I found the url where AJAX call is sent, but don't know how to find the method/function.

Comment: then edit your question and details what you have seen, without more informations it's hard to help you

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of that site?

Answer (score 0):

If the url is something like this  `admin-ajax.php?example_ajax_request=1&data=1234`

The add_action function in the code would be `wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request`

So, try to grep the whole of your theme directory or plugin directory for the text.

Example: `grep -r 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request' *`

The second parameter of the add_action is the function name you're looking for.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side for example of how it works.

Comment: NO it's not admin part of website. It's just front end part of website.

Comment: I am not talking about the admin part of the website, that is why added _nopriv_ to the function. It is for frontend only.

Comment: For more details on _nopriv_ refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)

Comment: @YuriiHalapup frontend AJAX requests that use that API will still call `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, even for logged out users on the homepage